# How can I launch the iOS Simulator from Terminal?

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal

I can build using the Xcode command line tools, is there any way I can actually run the application using them? (E.g. the equivalent to pressing Cmd+R in Xcode)

Comment: `open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app`?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

First decide what device you want to use:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

This will give you a list of devices:

```
-- iOS 9.0 --
    iPhone 4s (56632E02-650E-4C24-AAF4-5557FB1B8EB2) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 5 (ACD4DB7B-9FC9-49D5-B06B-BA5D5E2F5165) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 5s (A8358B76-AD67-4571-9EB7-FFF4D0AC029E) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 (1D46E980-C127-4814-A1E2-5BE47F6A15ED) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 Plus (FD9F726E-453A-4A4C-9460-A6C332AB140B) (Shutdown)
```

Choose the ID (eg. FD9F726E-453A-4A4C-9460-A6C332AB140B) you want (you can create your own device using `xcrun simctl create` if you want).

Boot the simulator with that device (replacing YOUR-DEVICE-ID with the ID)

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator -CurrentDeviceUDID <YOUR-DEVICE-ID>
```

Now you should be able to use simctl to install and launch commands.

```
xcrun simctl install <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> <PATH-TO-APPLICATION-BUNDLE>
xcrun simctl launch <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> <BUNDLE-ID-OF-APP-BUNDLE>
```

`xcrun simctl help` for more details. Note that booting a device using simctl does not currently (Xcode 7.2) allow you to do anything else with that device such as launch or install applications. You need to launch the device in the simulator to actually do anything interesting. Also, you cannot delete a device that is in use by the simulator, so you will have to quit/kill the simulator before attempting to delete anything.

Comment: A little tip.. once the device is booted, you can use the keyword `booted` instead of `<YOUR-DEVICE-ID>`.

Comment: You can find compiled application bundle in: 

`/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourApp-cuozdynseabctdefrjsejhldxden/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator`

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki Is there a command line to show that path ?

Comment: `open -a Simulator --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <YOUR-DEVICE-ID>` also works for starting the simulator

Comment: What is<PATH-TO-APPLICATION-BUNDLE> and <BUNDLE-ID-OF-APP-BUNDLE> ?

Comment: An example of path-to-application-bundle is `/MyDrive/MyFolder/MyApp.app`

An example of bundle-id-of-app-bundle is `com.mycompany.myapp`

Comment: When using only `open -a Simulator --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <YOUR-DEVICE-ID>` though I replaced the device id it was launching the same device. In the end, I had to use `xcrun simctl boot <YOUR-DEVICE-ID>` to boot another device.

Comment: The easiest way is - (open -a Simulator.app)

Comment: list command shows the error xcrun simctl list
2021-12-06 18:20:20.358 xcodebuild[12224:520286] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-18132/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/Foundation/Specifications/XCSpecification.m:1504
Details:  propertyList should be an instance inheriting from TSPropertyListDictionary, but it is nil
Object:   <XCSpecificationProxy: 0x7fca68666110>
Method:   -loadedSpecification
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fca667098d0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

Answer (score 326):

Type this in terminal:

```
open -a Simulator.app
```

Answer (score 158):

This worked for me:

```
open -a simulator
```

Comment: @Benjith Kizhisseri , this answer was already posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992522/6898523   please avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: @MAhipalSingh, I didn't see any `not appropriate` word in comment and As a reviewer there's predefine options where you only able to select from them.

Comment: I can't see why this "does not provide an answer to the question". This is the shortest answer to the question in this page and therefore this is a useful answer.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question because it doesn't run the application. The poster wanted something that would run an app for them, not just launch the simulator.

Comment: @MAhipalSingh `"simulator" != "Simulator.app" // true`

Answer (score 66):

This is the answer you are looking for:

1. Open terminal
2. `xcrun simctl list`
3. Get udid of the device you want to launch
4. Paste this in the terminal
5. `open -a Simulator --args -CurrentDeviceUDID 0566AC33-9B91-2DR2-B5BB-C916D3BA8MD3`

Comment: simply run directly into a selected device

Comment: If you need to run multiple specific simulators, this command will not work. Multiple calls to this command with different device UDIDs will not open more simulators.

use: `xcrun simctl boot <UDID>` if needing to boot multiple

Answer (score 33):

*Open your terminal and paste this code:*

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```

[image: iOS Simulator Folder Path]

Answer (score 20):

Use `xcrun simctl list` to get a list of simulators and their UDIDs.
Then open a specific simulator using `xcrun simctl boot <UDIDs>`

Comment: It should be noted that this does _boot_ the simulator, but does _not_ actually open the UI. For that, you still need `open -a Simulator`.

Comment: My list displays the error xcrun simctl list
2021-12-06 18:20:20.358 xcodebuild[12224:520286] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-18132/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/Foundation/Specifications/XCSpecification.m:1504
Details:  propertyList should be an instance inheriting from TSPropertyListDictionary, but it is nil
Object:   <XCSpecificationProxy: 0x7fca68666110>
Method:   -loadedSpecification
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fca667098d0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

Answer (score 9):

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app/
```

Comment: That will just launch the Simulator, I'm looking for a way to do the same as Cmd+R in the terminal, launching the Simulator AND running the app

Comment: The app must be installed trough Xcode to the simulator. Once you have done that at least once, you app will be saved on the simulator and accesible either from Xcode or Terminal. You can not compile by any means your code without Xcode @AlexChesters

Comment: @Llorgi you can build your code from the terminal without Xcode

Comment: Sure you can compile your code trough terminal. But you are still using `Xcode Command Line Tools`. Example `xcodebuild test -scheme MyiOSApp -destination 'platform=iOS,name=iPod touch'` @AlexChesters

Answer (score 7):

summing-up

`open -a Simulator && xcrun simctl boot 'iPhone 8 Plus'`

Comment: This worked perfectly for updating an Alfred workflow. Will expand into a tiny shell script as a standalone answer.

Answer (score 6):

**One of the best solution** :

- **Launch** iOS simulator from Terminal **by providing name of the device**

> **xcrun simctl boot $(xcrun simctl list devices | grep -m 1 'iPhone 12
> Pro' |grep -E -o -i '([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})')**

- This cmd will **seamlessly launch the ios simulator** for 'iPhone 12 Pro' device

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: I am using this code snippet on daily basis @ICW I think you missed to put this cmd in terminal to execute and if using in groovy then use sh cmd. I hope this will help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a handy command to build the project and then run it in the terminal:

```
xcodebuild -scheme <scheme_name> -destination <destination_name> build && xcrun simctl launch booted <bundle_identifier>
```

`<scheme_name>` - the name of the specific schema, e.g. `"MyApp (Dev Environment)"`

`<destination_name>` - the name of the simulator on which to run. For example `"name=iPhone 14 Pro"`

`<bundle_identifier>` - bundle of your project. Example: `com.johnne.myapp`

---

Execution result:

1. The project will be built first;
2. If the build was successful, your project will run on the selected simulator.

---

The final command with the data above will look like this:

`xcodebuild -scheme "MyApp (Dev Environment)" -destination "name=iPhone 14 Pro" build && xcrun simctl launch booted com.johnne.myapp`

Answer (score 0):

As [promised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179706/how-can-i-launch-the-ios-simulator-from-terminal/75157159#comment136570721_75157159), wrote a [tiny shell script](https://gist.github.com/pythoninthegrass/7cd17066d3b40a1d453747ea9a764993) to launch the XCode Simulator from the command line. Takes the advice from this thread and builds a user prompt around `xcrun simctl list` and `xcrun simctl boot`.

**Quickstart**

```
λ run-ios-sim
Enter phone model (e.g., iPhone 13 mini):
iphone 13
Choose a device type:
1 iPhone 13 Pro
2 iPhone 13 Pro Max
3 iPhone 13 mini
4 iPhone 13
```

**Pass argument directly**

```
λ run-ios-sim iphone 13 mini
Choose a device type:
1 iPhone 13 mini
1
iPhone 13 mini already booted
```

**General usage**

```
λ run-ios-sim -h
Run iOS simulator from the command line.

USAGE
./run-ios-sim [device_type] (e.g., "iPhone 13 mini")
OPTIONS
    -h --help     Show this help message.
    -l --list     List available device types.
    -i            Install script to ~/.local/bin (then call as `run-ios-sim`).
```

Happy to turn into a proper repo if there's enough interest

Answer (score -2):

You can Replace version:

`npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 13'`

Comment: This question asks for the command to open simulator via terminal. And here you're  mentioning a way to run our react native app on a specified simulator.