# How to compile iOS app to multiple Simulators simultaneously?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, ios-simulator

I have to fix an iOS App for iPhone X, and need to change some constraints.
Before testing I need to make sure that the app looks OK on multiple devices, so I want to compile to each of these device simulators (i.e. iPhone X, 8, 8 Plus, SE).

Is it possible to do so in a single step, I.E. launch multiple simulators one next to the other, to compare their design?

Comment: you want the title of the post to say simulator. i thought you are talking about sim cards. Once simulator is running, you can click in menu bar on hardware > device > iOS and select different ones.

Comment: @user770, I want to compile to different SIMs, but doing that one by one and waiting to load is slow, so I want to compile on all 4 at the same time, then to open all of the SIMs and then to compare design

Comment: @new2ios - you could write a script to launch / run your app on multiple simulators from the command line (terminal) in one stroke. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262865/6257435

Comment: 10x, @DonMag. This looks promising.