# How do you power-down an iPhone X in the Xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, iphone-x

I run the Xcode Simulator on its own for web development testing. When Simulator starts up, it always boots up the iPhone X (iOS 11.3) because it was running when I last quit the simulator, because I can't figure out how to shut down the phone.

I can't hit the (virtual) power and volume buttons at the same time in the simulator (as one would do on a real phone) and for some reason the Settings > General area doesn't have the option to "Shut Down." I can restart the device from the Simulator's "Hardware" menu but there does not seem to be an option for shutting down the phone (even with extra keyboard modifiers held).

Have I missed anything or is this just not possible?

**Clarifications:**

- I'm only running the simulator to use Safari on various platforms. There is no program instance to deactivate. Xcode is not running (or doesn't need to be running after the Simulator is launched from the Xcode menu). I have also tried launching, say, an iPhone 6S simulation from a compiled Xcode project but this only launches that hardware for that run. Next time I go directly into the Simulator, it remembers which hardware simulations were running and launches those.
- I can select a different piece of hardware from the Hardware menu (e.g., iPhone 6S) but now I have **two** simulations running, which is resource intensive (and undesirable). I can shutdown the 6S because I can hold down the (virtual) power button to instruct the OS to perform its shutdown routine. But I can't shut down the iPhone X because there's no way (that I can find) to command the OS to shutdown like I can with anything else. The software method (in Settings) doesn't show in the simulator (for some strange reason) and the hardware method requires hitting two buttons at the same time. The net result is, now that I launched an iPhone X once, I always have to simulate an iPhone X + whatever I'm actually testing against.

**Workaround Found**

When Simulator is launched on its own (not though an Xcode project) it will re-launch the last simulation that was activated from the Hardware menu *if* it's left running. So if I launch something new, and then leave both it and the iPhone X simulator running, When I quit Simulator it will relaunch with the next time with new hardware, not the iPhone X.

I'd still be interested in any method to just tell the iPhone X hardware to shut down (if such a thing exists) as I'm often having to flip between hardware simulations and it would good to be able to do that without having to relaunch to get rid of iPhone X.

Comment: you have to quit the program instance. there is no shut down mode.

Comment: You can launch a specific simulator from the command line (terminal). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262865/6257435

Comment: I'm having a little trouble picturing the problem you want to solve, but the  link from @DonMag is likely the right direction. You almost certainly want to use `simctl`. You can shutdown a simulator with that, for example, and launch specific apps in specific simulators.

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm doing web development and I want to see Safari running a web app: on an iPad, then the iPhone X, then SE, then back to X, etc. (So the problem to be solved is needing to constantly switch between emulators but not being able to "turn off" an iPhone X. DonMag's answer is good but Tushar has a better one: Apparently simulators can just be closed like regular windows. ::forehead slap::

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change your simulator to required version from Hardware -> Device -> 
That way you will have correct version loaded and of course there is no way of "Shutdown" a simulator but quit, as this is just an application not hardware.
If you have multiple simulators open, you can close the not required ones by highlighting them and select File -> Close Window or CMD+W

Another good info from Colin :

> I also just noticed that if I turn off "show device bezels" I get
>   regular window controls for closing the window, too.

Comment: I'm afraid the hardware menu doesn't "change" the simulated device it only "adds another" simulated device.

Comment: If you have multiple simulators open, you can close the not required ones by highlighting them and select File -> Close Window or CMD+W

Comment: Yes! Thank-you! If you want to update your answer above, I'd be happy mark it as correct. (I also just noticed that if I turn off "show device bezels" I get regular window controls for closing the window, too.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also to go to Settings > General and Shut Down should be at the very bottom