# How to launch multiple Xcode simulators from terminal?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

To open one simulator, I can run `open -a Simulator --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <iPhone-11-Pro-DEVICE-ID>` in my terminal, and the simulator for iPhone 11 Pro will open.

To open two (or more) simulators, I want to do something like `open -a Simulator --args <iPhone-11-Pro-DEVICE-ID> <iPhone-11-Pro-Max-DEVICE-ID>` to open **both** iPhone 11 and iPhone 11 Pro Max simulators.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why aren’t you using `simctl`?

Comment: Because I didn't know where to find the bundle ID.  I think the command is `xcrun simctl launch <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> <BUNDLE-ID-OF-APP-BUNDLE>` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262865/6946549)

Answer (score 1):

With Simulator.app running, use `xcrun simctl boot <UDID>` to boot additional devices.  Sumulator.app will show them.