# The simulator doesn't open when running detox test on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, detox

When I try to run `detox test` the simulator doesn't appear to open and the tests just time out.

I confirmed that my setup is correct and also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179706/how-can-i-launch-the-ios-simulator-from-terminal) to make sure my simulator can be launched from the terminal and that the device types in my `detox` config are correct.

The errors I receive are below.

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

and

```
DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

HINT: There was an error on attempt to call detox.init()

DetoxRuntimeError: Aborted detox.init() execution, and now running detox.cleanup()

HINT: Most likely, your test runner is tearing down the suite due to the timeout error
```

Here is my config with the app names removed for privacy reasons.

```
"ios.sim.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app",
    "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/example.xcworkspace -scheme example -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11 Pro"
    }
},
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that starting with Xcode 9 `detox` runs the iOS simulator in headless mode. If you are running the tests and then use Spotlight to pull up the simulator and hit enter then it will bring all of the simulators `detox` has opened to the front.

[image]

I discovered this from this [comment](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/389#issuecomment-342138575).

I also figured out that the reason my tests were timing out is that there was a prompt that the user needed to respond to which was blocking the `detox` tests from progressing.

Comment: my spotlight isn't finding the simulator from xcode..

Comment: for me searching "simulator" in the Xcode help menu then hitting enter on "Open Developer tool -> Simulator" opened up the simulator when my spotlight couldn't find it.

Comment: Hi, were you able to have the simulator launch without having to explicitly search for it on Spotlight? I have the same issue. I tried playing around with the `headless` property, but it didn't work. It seems it's only for Android.

Comment: @RameezHussain I left whatever the default detox behavior was in place. You could try making a separate script that runs before your detox tests and launches the simulator. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179706/how-can-i-launch-the-ios-simulator-from-terminal) has some steps for customizing the launch behavior of the simulator from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have detox .init method hooked to your tests.
Make sure you have **e2e/init.js** and there you would need to add

```
before(async () => {
     await detox.init(config);
});
```

Also make sure you call this file in **config.json** (might be wrong here, I'm using Mocha and mocha.opts instead there)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I did follow all of the docs exactly for my setup, `e2e/init.js`, `config.json` etc... The issue for me ended up being that the iOS simulator was running in headless mode so it was working but I didn't visually see it so I thought it was broken.

Comment: glad you figured this out