# Opening specific simulator on Mac book

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I got some problem in opening IOS (iphone/ipad) simulator on Mac running Big Sur. when I run the below code iphone 12 pro max (ios 14.x) simulator had been opened.

```
open -a simulator
```

I would like to open the specific simulator such as iphone 11, iphone 10 pr.
how would I open it?

Thanks,
jm

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179706/how-can-i-launch-the-ios-simulator-from-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using Terminal you could do the following:

Open the Simulator app from Spotlight:

```
cmd + spacebar -> Search "Simulator" -> Enter
```

Then on the Simulator app do:

```
File -> Open Simulator -> Select iOS version -> Select device type.
```

Then pin the Simulator app to your dock by pressing and holding the Simulator app icon, hover over options and select `Keep in Dock`.

Answer (score 0):

This may have changed, on mine currently

file > New Simulator

there you choose what you would like to test then click create.

In Monterey 12.6