# Visual Studio Code - Flutter : "iOS emulator is offline"

Tags: flutter

My Vscode has been detecting my iOS simulator as offline, however when i a start it from vscode the simulator runs and opens well but throws an error "Failed to launch iOS Simulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds"[image]

Answer (score 0):

try explicit open at xcode, don't at vscode

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179706/how-can-i-launch-the-ios-simulator-from-terminal)

Comment: simulator opens well, but its not detected by vscode, still shows it as offline

Comment: have you try flutter doctor?

Comment: everything is fine

Comment: so last option for me just reinstall your vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).